# Jest not recognizing spy is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm having a little trouble confirming my function is called using Jest. I've got two mocked functions. One is just mocked to return a promise, the other is a simple spy that should be called in the `then()` block of the first.

Below, in the test, you will see two expectations. The first expectation passes. The second does not. i.e. `expect(sendSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()` passes but `expect(sendCallbackSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()` does not.

However, when I put the `console.log` statements in the file (as below), both execute (i.e. the 'before' and 'after'), and if I console log the `window.props.onSend` it confirms that the mocked function is present. So it looks like the function should be called.

Another thing of note is that my implementation requires me to pass in the callback in a `props` object from my `window`. Further, to mock things on the `window` in Jest, you just mock `global` as I'm doing below. I don't think that is relevant to the issue but worth pointing out nonetheless.

Could it be that the expectation is run before the actual function is called in the `then()` block?

```
export class MyButton extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.send(this.props.url).then(res => {
      console.log('before', window.props.onSend)
      window.props.onSend(res.data)
      console.log('after')
    })
  }

  render() {
     return <button onClick={handleClick} />
  }
}



//test

  test('it calls the identity function when button is clicked', () => {
    const sendSpy = jest.fn(() => { return Promise.resolve({ data: 'hello' }) })
    const sendCallbackSpy = jest.fn()
    global.props = { onSend: sendCallbackSpy }

    wrapper = shallow(<MyButton send={sendSpy} } />)
    const button = wrapper.find('button')
    button.simulate('click')

    expect(sendSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(sendCallbackSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for the promise before testing the second spy:

```
test('it calls the identity function when button is clicked', async() => {
    const request = Promise.resolve({ data: 'hello' })
    const sendSpy = jest.fn(() => request)
    const sendCallbackSpy = jest.fn()
    global.props = { onSend: sendCallbackSpy }

    wrapper = shallow(<MyButton send={sendSpy} } />)
    const button = wrapper.find('button')
    button.simulate('click')

    expect(sendSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    await request
    expect(sendCallbackSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```